# Creating Models under different modules

Tags: playframework-2.0

I would like to have following structure in my play! app.

App
|_  controllers
|_  Modules
      |- Module1
           |- models
      |- Module2
            - models

Basically, I would like to use seperate models in each module.

However all my persistence layer throwing error in such structure. I tried to set my app config to access each models explicitly [rather than models.*] but no luck.

One possible workaround would be sharing models in module1 and module2 but I would like to keep them inside the individual models since they have no common use.

I really appreciate if you guys can help.

Thanks in advance,

P.S.: I am on latest version of play 2.0.2 and using MySQL 5.5 as persistent unit

ED